# Form field is turning grey in one field on iphone/ipad Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

Hi I have created a form on my website, however when i open the website on an iphone or ipad i have one formfield that turns grey (the dropdown) I already tried a lot of css but it doesn't help.

does any one had the same problem and know how to solve it?

[image: d]

Comment: try adding the css `-webkit-appearance:none;`

Comment: I will post as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a css

```
-webkit-appearance:none;
```